# Tapioca DSL - undefined method `api_token` for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet

I am a new ruby on rails developer coming from Javascript and Typescript word.
I have been assigned to a project and my first task is to set up `sorbet`. It's a really nice tool.

I follow this [tutorial](https://nithinbekal.com/posts/sorbet-rails/) which really helps me to understand what `sorbet` aims and I read the documentation.

I then try to implement that in the project but I am having some errors I don't understand

I first ran `bundle exec tapioca init` and I got this error

```
  identical  sorbet/config
   identical  sorbet/tapioca/config.yml
   identical  sorbet/tapioca/require.rb
       force  bin/tapioca
Retrieving index from central repository... Done
Listing gems from Gemfile.lock... Done
Removing annotations for gems that have been removed...  Nothing to do
Fetching gem annotations from central repository...

  Fetched aasm
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/aasm.rbi

  Fetched actionmailer
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/actionmailer.rbi

  Fetched actionpack
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/actionpack.rbi

  Fetched actionview
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/actionview.rbi

  Fetched activemodel
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/activemodel.rbi

  Fetched activerecord
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/activerecord.rbi

  Fetched activesupport
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/activesupport.rbi

  Fetched colorize
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/colorize.rbi

  Fetched faraday
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/faraday.rbi

  Fetched globalid
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/globalid.rbi

  Fetched pundit
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/pundit.rbi

  Fetched railties
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/railties.rbi

  Fetched rainbow
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/rainbow.rbi

  Fetched sidekiq
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/sidekiq.rbi

  Fetched sidekiq-scheduler
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/sidekiq-scheduler.rbi

  Fetched stripe
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/stripe.rbi

  Fetched webmock
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/webmock.rbi

Done
Removing RBI files of gems that have been removed:

  Nothing to do.

Generating RBI files of gems that are added or updated:

Requiring all gems to prepare for compiling...  Done

E, [2023-08-23T12:46:24.891946 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.034636 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.183607 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.330612 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.339680 #5926] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Audited::RspecMatchers

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.486924 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.563776 #5926] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Audited::RspecMatchers

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
#<Thread:0x000000011898c8d0 /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/parallel-1.23.0/lib/parallel.rb:219 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.628656 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.783266 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.823917 #5926] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Audited::RspecMatchers

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- backburner (LoadError)
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activejob-7.0.6/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/backburner_adapter.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:278:in `const_get'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:278:in `constantize'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:74:in `constantize'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/lookbook-1.5.3/lib/lookbook/entities/collections/preview_collection.rb:22:in `preview_from_code_object'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/lookbook-1.5.3/lib/lookbook/entities/collections/preview_collection.rb:17:in `block in load'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/lookbook-1.5.3/lib/lookbook/entities/collections/preview_collection.rb:17:in `map'
  identical  sorbet/config
   identical  sorbet/tapioca/config.yml
   identical  sorbet/tapioca/require.rb
       force  bin/tapioca
Retrieving index from central repository... Done
Listing gems from Gemfile.lock... Done
Removing annotations for gems that have been removed...  Nothing to do
Fetching gem annotations from central repository...

  Fetched aasm
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/aasm.rbi

  Fetched actionmailer
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/actionmailer.rbi

  Fetched actionpack
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/actionpack.rbi

  Fetched actionview
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/actionview.rbi

  Fetched activemodel
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/activemodel.rbi

  Fetched activerecord
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/activerecord.rbi

  Fetched activesupport
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/activesupport.rbi

  Fetched colorize
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/colorize.rbi

  Fetched faraday
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/faraday.rbi

  Fetched globalid
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/globalid.rbi

  Fetched pundit
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/pundit.rbi

  Fetched railties
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/railties.rbi

  Fetched rainbow
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/rainbow.rbi

  Fetched sidekiq
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/sidekiq.rbi

  Fetched sidekiq-scheduler
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/sidekiq-scheduler.rbi

  Fetched stripe
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/stripe.rbi

  Fetched webmock
   identical  sorbet/rbi/annotations/webmock.rbi

Done
Removing RBI files of gems that have been removed:

  Nothing to do.

Generating RBI files of gems that are added or updated:

Requiring all gems to prepare for compiling...  Done

E, [2023-08-23T12:46:24.891946 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.034636 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.183607 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.330612 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.339680 #5926] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Audited::RspecMatchers

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.486924 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.563776 #5926] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Audited::RspecMatchers

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
#<Thread:0x000000011898c8d0 /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/parallel-1.23.0/lib/parallel.rb:219 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.628656 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.783266 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.823917 #5926] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Audited::RspecMatchers

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- backburner (LoadError)
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activejob-7.0.6/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/backburner_adapter.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:278:in `const_get'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:278:in `constantize'
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.931097 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:25.959616 #5924] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Annotate::Parser

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
Did you mean?  Unparser
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:26.052651 #5926] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Audited::RspecMatchers

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
E, [2023-08-23T12:46:26.091839 #5920] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActsAsTenant::Sidekiq
```

Those errors messages and from the 3rd or 4th execution of the command. But the errors are identical.

Seriously I don't understand why those error.

They are mentioning some constant but none of those constant are present in the code.

And there is also this error `/Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in` require': cannot load such file -- backburner (LoadError)`.` backburner`is not present in the code but`bootsnap` is present

I have this `gem "bootsnap", ">= 1.4.2", require: false` in the `Gemfile` and this `require "bootsnap/setup" # Speed up boot time by caching expensive operations.` in `config/boot.rb`

After running that command, I decided to run the next command `bin/tapioca dsl` thinking that things will go well but I got another error

```
Loading Rails application... D, [2023-08-23T13:21:38.074279 #7210] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: 169.254.169.254:80
D, [2023-08-23T13:21:39.285794 #7210] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: metadata.google.internal:80
D, [2023-08-23T13:21:39.493409 #7210] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: 169.254.169.254:80
D, [2023-08-23T13:21:40.540914 #7210] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: collector.newrelic.com:443

Tapioca attempted to load the Rails application after encountering a `config/application.rb` file, but it failed. If your application uses Rails please ensure it can be loaded correctly before generating RBIs. If your application does not use Rails and you wish to continue RBI generation please pass `--no-halt-upon-load-error` to the tapioca command in sorbet/tapioca/config.yml or in CLI.
undefined method `api_token' for nil:NilClass

    BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME = Rails.application.credentials.esignatures.api_token.freeze
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
D, [2023-08-23T13:21:43.046564 #7210] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Sending: POST http://collector.newrelic.com:443/agent_listener/invoke_raw_method?protocol_version=17&license_key=b059b8e82921a9b4a97e75f1af1ca00fd8e3NRAL&method=preconnect&marshal_format=json
D, [2023-08-23T13:21:43.046769 #7210] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Status: 200
D, [2023-08-23T13:21:43.050622 #7210] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: collector.newrelic.com:443
/Users/maelfosso/Documents/vola-app/app/controllers/webhooks/esignatures_controller.rb:5:in `<class:EsignaturesController>': undefined method `api_token' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME = Rails.application.credentials.esignatures.api_token.freeze
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
    from /Users/maelfosso/Documents/vola-app/app/controllers/webhooks/esignatures_controller.rb:4:in `<module:Webhooks>'
    from /Users/maelfosso/Documents/vola-app/app/controllers/webhooks/esignatures_controller.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `const_get'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `cget'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:175:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in `block in ls'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:170:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:379:in `block in eager_load_all'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:377:in `each'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:377:in `eager_load_all'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca/loaders/loader.rb:206:in `eager_load_rails_app'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `bind_call'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `block in _on_method_added'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca/loaders/loader.rb:60:in `load_rails_application'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `bind_call'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `block in _on_method_added'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca/loaders/dsl.rb:74:in `load_application'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `bind_call'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `block in _on_method_added'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca/loaders/dsl.rb:29:in `load'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `bind_call'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `block in _on_method_added'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca/loaders/dsl.rb:22:in `load_application'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `bind_call'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `block in _on_method_added'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca/commands/dsl.rb:98:in `execute'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `bind_call'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `block in _on_method_added'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca/cli.rb:164:in `block in dsl'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca.rb:23:in `block in silence_warnings'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:46:in `use_ui'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca.rb:22:in `silence_warnings'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `bind_call'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.10981/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:277:in `block in _on_method_added'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/lib/tapioca/cli.rb:160:in `dsl'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /Users/maelfosso/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tapioca-0.11.8/exe/tapioca:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/tapioca:29:in `load'
    from bin/tapioca:29:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand it.

Please, any idea ?

Comment: There are probably a few different things going on here. Tapioca is still under active development, so it's not surprising to run into a few issues while setting it up. And doing so while new to Rails may be challenging. But as a starting point, were you able to successfully boot the app on your local machine, before you tried adding Sorbet (e.g. with `rails console`)?

Comment: @AndyWaite `rails console` is running correctly. I have access to the console. For example, I can run requests from some models (`Account.all`).